# In Kentucky, did one man beat up another man after they both bought the same woman's vote?

Tags: united-states, criminology, voting

According to the Washington Post article [Selling votes is common type of election fraud](https://www.washingtonpost.com/politics/decision2012/selling-votes-is-common-type-of-election-fraud/2012/10/01/f8f5045a-071d-11e2-81ba-ffe35a7b6542_story.html?utm_term=.e486e37a2328):

> corrupt candidates in Clay County, Ky., once paid $100. But that was probably too much: It attracted one woman who already had sold her vote. The man who bought it first was outraged, and he beat up the man who bought it second.

Is this a true story?

Comment: When it says "once" I'm imagining it was 50 years ago...

Comment: *"Selling votes is common type of election fraud"*. Eh... no. from the **same publication** as you quoted: [**Here are nine investigations on voter fraud that found virtually nothing**](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/wonk/wp/2017/01/25/here-are-nine-major-investigations-on-voter-fraud-that-found-virtually-nothing/)

Comment: @MichaelK Excellent point.  The OP article is from 2012, but now the same title wouldn't correspond to the paper's bias.  Only a paper with the opposite bias would have a title like that now.

Answer (score 9):

**Maybe.**

[Official FBI Press Release](https://archives.fbi.gov/archives/louisville/press-releases/2010/lo032510.htm) of the convictions in 2010, there were eight defendants in total. From the [Lexington Herald Leader](http://www.kentucky.com/news/local/crime/article44083767.html):

> In one of those cases, vote-buyer Bobby Red Sams testified that [William Bart Morris], who was working for a different candidate than Sams, beat him up in a dispute over a woman who had sold her vote.

Morris was one of the defendants in the Federal [RICO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Racketeer_Influenced_and_Corrupt_Organizations_Act) case. My interpretation of the claim hinges on Mr. Sams' testimony (which I cannot find a transcript of), which is why my conclusion is "maybe". I could not find any charges against a Bobby Red Sams for perjury, or even mention of a plea deal for someone described as a "vote buyer".

[Here](http://www.opn.ca6.uscourts.gov/opinions.pdf/13a0179p-06.pdf) is a link to an appellate court's ruling to vacate all of the defendants' convictions in 2013, and another article from the [Lexington Herald Leader](http://www.kentucky.com/news/politics-government/article44434632.html) describing it. Nothing in either source discounts Mr. Sams' testimony directly. Morris, his wife, and the rest of the defendants later [plead guilty](https://www.justice.gov/usao-edky/pr/former-clay-county-officials-admit-racketeering-conspiracy) to a "racketeering conspiracy" charge, but not for assault. As part of the deal Mr. Morris [agreed to serve 5½ years](http://www.kentucky.com/news/state/kentucky/article44442576.html) in federal prison.

The original case was [USA v. Maricle et al](https://www.gpo.gov/fdsys/search/pagedetails.action?granuleId=USCOURTS-kyed-6_09-cr-00016-22&packageId=USCOURTS-kyed-6_09-cr-00016).

I haven't yet seen anything in any of the sources that mentions the cost of the vote, which to me seems to be a pretty small amount to be paid for breaking a federal law.